# Create a list of types in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, collections

I'd like to create a list of types, each of which must implement a particular interface.  Like:

```
interface IBase { }
interface IDerived1 : IBase { }
interface IDerived2 : IBase { }

class HasATypeList
{
    List<typeof(IBase)> items;
    HasATypeList()
    {
        items.Add(typeof(IDerived1));
    }

}
```

So I know I can do

```
List<Type> items;
```

But that won't limit the allowable types in the list to ones that implement IBase.  Do I have to write my own list class?  Not that it's a big deal, but if I don't have to...

Comment: I thought I had the answer but you're right - you don't want a list of IBase-implementing objects, you want a list of TYPE's that implement that interface. I think you have to implement your own list with extra logic in Add

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typeof(IBase)`, `typeof(object)`, `typeof(Foo)`, all return an instance of `Type`, with the same members and so on.

I don't see what you're trying to achieve and why you want to make a distinction between those ?

In fact, the code you're writing here:

```
List<typeof(IBase)> items;
```

(i don't even know if this compiles ? )
Is exactly the same as this:

```
List<Type> items;
```

So in fact, what you're trying to achieve is imho useless.

If you really want to achieve this -but I do not see why ... -, you can always create your own collection-type like Olivier Jacot-Descombes is suggesting, but in that case, I'd rather create a type that inherits from `Collection<T>` instead:

```
public class MyTypeList<T> : Collection<Type>
{
    protected override InsertItem( int index, Type item )
    {
        if( !typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(item) )
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("the Type does not derive from ... ");
        }

        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing.  I was just wondering if there was a cleverer way to do it.  For example using a where clause or something...

Comment: And I don't think it's useless.  I want a list of types where all types in the list must implement a certain interface.

Comment: And what are you going to do with that list ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have to implement a List that throws exceptions if type is not a subclass from IBase.

There is no built in way to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do that is to create your own type collection

```
public class MyTypeList
{
    List<Type> _innerList;

    public void Add(Type type)
    {
        if (typeof(IBase).IsAssignableFrom(type)) {
             _innerList.Add(type);
        } else {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "Type must be IBase, implement or derive from it.");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```